# Related to blackberry application development

Tags: validation, blackberry, phone-number

I have an edit field and I want  to use it for numeric value.

Can anyone tell me how to enter only numeric value in edit field, I want to use it for phone number. I used `BasicEditField.numeric` but didn't work.

I also want to validate it in proper format....ddd-ddd-dddd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `BasicEditField` with `FILTER_PHONE`? Example can be found [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Editable_text_field_1211033_11.jsp).

I've never seen anything you could use for validation you need in the BB API. RegExps are not supported in BB API, so you'll most likely have to write your own validator.